# Questions on delete[] operator when pointer to an array is involved

Tags: c++, arrays

The following code compiles but runs with mistake:

```
int main() {
    int (*d)[2] = new int[3][2];
    // do something
    delete [] *d; // this is wrong
    delete [] *(d+1); // this is also wrong
    //delete [] d; // this works
    return 0;
}
```

I do not know why "delete [] *d" does not work because *d seems to be a pointer to a chunk containing 2 integers and delete[] should destroy that chunk.

Furthermore, I am not sure whether "delete [] d" is enough to release all six elements since two-dimension array is involved here.

Thanks!

Comment: `delete` what you `new`, and only what you `new`.  The new-expression here returned `d`, not `*d` and not `*(d+1)`.

Comment: `int (*d)[2]` says "`*d` is an array of two ints". An array is not a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The memory you allocated is allocated as one continuous block (or chunk) of memory that stores an array obejct of `int[3][2]` type. It should be freed as one block

```
delete [] d;
```

That's all you need to do.

Freeing just some partial sub-block of a whole block is not supported by C++ dynamic memory management mechanisms.

Your `delete [] *d` is indeed wrong - the behavior is undefined. However, it has a good chance of "working" in practice since `int (*)[2]` pointer `d` and [decayed] `int *` pointer `*d` point to the same spot in memory, and the underlying types are trivial. If it "works", it should typically have the same effect as `delete [] d;`, i.e. free the entire 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

`int[3][2]` is not a pointer of pointers but just a multi-dimensional array, allocated as a single pointer.

You cannot delete "lines" of it because there are no lines. Memory is contiguous.